# Unable to make request to service running in Minikube tunnel

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am working on an API that I will deploy with Kubernetes and I want to test it locally.

I created the Docker image, successfully tested it locally, and pushed it to a public Docker registry. Now I would like to deploy in a Kubernetes cluster and there are no errors being thrown, however, I am not able to make a request to the endpoint exposed by the Minikube tunnel.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start Minikube container: `minikube start --ports=127.0.0.1:30000:30000`
2. Create deployment and service: `kubectl apply -f fastapi.yaml`
3. Start minikube tunnel: `minikube service fastapi-server`

Encountered the following error: `192.168.49.2 took too long to respond.`

requirements.txt:

```
anyio==3.6.1
asgiref==3.5.2
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.4
fastapi==0.78.0
h11==0.13.0
httptools==0.4.0
idna==3.3
pydantic==1.9.1
python-dotenv==0.20.0
PyYAML==6.0
sniffio==1.2.0
starlette==0.19.1
typing_extensions==4.2.0
uvicorn==0.17.6
watchgod==0.8.2
websockets==10.3
```

main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"status": "OK"}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r ./requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

fastapi.yaml:

```
# deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: fastapi-server
  name: fastapi-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fastapi-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fastapi-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: fastapi-server
          image: smdf/fastapi-test
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
---
# service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: fastapi-server
  name: fastapi-server
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you did not set the service selector:

```yaml
# service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: fastapi-server
  name: fastapi-server
spec:
  selector:               <------------- Missing part
    app: fastapi-server   <-------------
  type: NodePort          <------------- Set the type to NodePort 
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 30000
```

---

#### How to check if your service is defined properly?

I checked to see if there are any `endpoints`, and there weren't any since you did not "attach" the service to your deployment

```bash
kubectl get endpoints -A
```

[image]

---

[image]

---

For more info you can read this section under my GitHub
https://github.com/nirgeier/KubernetesLabs/tree/master/Labs/05-Services

---

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the help. I applied the suggested changes to the fastapi.yaml file, however, I get the same results as before when entering `kubectl get endpoints -A`. Also, I was wondering how you knew which IP and port to make the request to based on what was printed after you entered `kubectl get all -A` in the second photo?

Comment: Following up with this solution, I finally discovered that the service is actually running/listneing on http://127.0.0.1:61340/. Do you have any insight into why that might be? Given that above it shows IP 172.17.0.3:8000?

Comment: Sure, since you are using NodePort K8S assign you an internal port for the connection, you can see it in the first screenshot (30000 there). That is the meaning of nodeport, assign a unique port across the cluster which allows you to connect to it using the <cluster_ip>:<port>

Comment: But it seems that the port is 61340 and not 30000, as expected

Comment: it can be random port, the 30000 is due to the minikube start flags